# Passing array of ints from ajax call (via token-input) to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I've been trying to pass an array of int's created by the following function:

```
function getCurrentSwimmerList() {
    var swimmerList = [];
    $("#swimmerTable >  tbody > tr").each(function () {
        swimmerList.push( parseInt($(this).data('swimmerid')) );
    });
    return swimmerList;
}
```

Which I use in token-input to eliminate ceartin suggestions from the search box, so I've set up token-input up like so:

```
$("#swimmerTokenInput").tokenInput("Admin/retrieveTokensForQuery", {
            urlParams: { "IDsAlreadyAdded": getCurrentSwimmerList },
```

I modified the token-input file to allow you to pass additional paramters in a request by setting `urlParams`, the addition I made to the  code was (in the appropriate section):

```
//add params passed in as urlParams
if (settings.urlParams != null) {
    for (var key in settings.urlParams) {
        if (settings.urlParams.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            ajax_params.data[key] = settings.urlParams[key];
        }
    }
}
```

I tested and I successfully get these values in the query string (where `Ol` was typed into the search box):

```
IDsAlreadyAdded=5%2C6&q=Ol
```

Which chrome recognizes and parses correctly:

```
IDsAlreadyAdded:5,6
q:Ol
```

The signature of the method I'm calling is as follows:

```
public JsonResult retrieveTokensForQuery(string q, int[] IDsAlreadyAdded)
```

Each time `q` successfully get's the appropriate value, however `IDsAlreadyAdded` *always* gets a null value. I've looked at various answers on SO (trying `traditional=true`, or `IdsAlreadyAdded[] = ...`, having `List<int>` or `IEnumerable<int>`) to try fix the problem, but I couldn't get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always create a custom model binder that maps the string value to an int[] like this:

```
public class IntArrayModelBinder : System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueProviderResult.AttemptedValue))
        {
            var items = valueProviderResult.AttemptedValue.Split(',');
            var result = new int[items.Length];
            for (var counter = 0; counter < items.Length; counter++)
            {
                result[counter] = int.Parse(items[counter]);
            }
            return result;
        }
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

and then just register the binder when you initialise your routing:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(int[]), new IntArrayModelBinder());
```

Comment: how do I register the model-binder to a specific route?

Comment: Custom model binders are mapping helpers for MVC when MVC is unable to figure out how to bind a specific type. Any time MVC sees a route with an int[] parameter, it will first attempt to parse the value using the custom binder above. So, this basically binds it for every route with an int[] parameter.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly, I had to edit it slightly though, I changed one line to `result[counter] = int.Parse(items[counter]);` was needed, otherwise the array was populated with `0`s by default. cheers :)